# Ranking array Java

Tags: java, arrays, rank

I am trying to rank my array in my assignment but I don't understand how to do it. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance

I added an image of the full assignment instructions.

Here is an image of my assignment:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
public class Assignment_3_Question_1 {
    // Here, I predefined my data set.
    static int referenceScore[][]={{39,40,17,35,42,6},{40,41,27,41,42,36},{42,40,26,42,42,35}};
    static int finalScore[][]={{39,40,17,35,42,6},{40,41,27,41,42,36},{42,40,26,42,42,35}};
    static int scoreAmongOthers[][]=new int[3][6];
    static int max;
    static int rank = 1;
    static int count = 0;
    static int total = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            max = referenceScore[0][0];
            for (int team = 0; team < 3; team++){
                for (int position = 0; position < 6; position++){
                    if (max < referenceScore[team][position]){
                        max = referenceScore[team][position];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++){
                    if(referenceScore[x][y]==max){
                        scoreAmongOthers[x][y]=rank;
                        referenceScore[x][y]=0;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            rank = count + 1;
        }
        // Print out the  
        System.out.println("\tP1\tP2\tP3\tP4\tP5\tP6\tTotal\tRank");

        // Prints out the results and the rank for each team
        for(int teamNb = 0; teamNb<3; teamNb++){
            System.out.print("Team"+(teamNb+1));
            for(int p=0; p<6; p++){
                total = total + finalScore[teamNb][p];
                System.out.print("\t" + finalScore[teamNb][p]+"("+ scoreAmongOthers[teamNb][p]+") ");
            }
            System.out.print("\t"+ total);
            total = 0;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the array {3, 3, 4, 2},be ranked {2, 2, 3, 1}?  What parts of the assignment do you feel you can code?  You've written a lot of code for someone that doesn't understand the problem statement.  You can also use methods to break up your code into smaller, more easily testable pieces.

Comment: Do you have any limitations on your implementation? I'm thinking to use a linked list. Is that allowed?

Comment: What is a linked list?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Here’s what our teacher told us about how we could do the ranking: it isn’t the same as sorting. You create a new array, no need to change the original array.1- create a method to rank a 1-D array. 2-Algorithm of ranking: for each element in the input array, count how many elements are bigger than it, then its rank is the number+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I understand that the point of the exercise is to practice working with arrays. You have outlined the required algorithm in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698495/ranking-array-java#comment107393818_60698495). Here is my implementation.

```java
public class RankScores {
    private static int getRank(int[][] scores, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int count = 0;
        int score = scores[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        for (int row = 0; row < scores.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < scores[row].length; col++) {
                if (scores[row][col] > score) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count + 1;
    }

    private static int getTeamRank(int[] scores, int index) {
        int count = 0;
        int score = scores[index];
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (scores[i] > score) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int referenceScore[][]={{39,40,17,35,42,6},{40,41,27,41,42,36},{42,40,26,42,42,35}};
        int ranks[][] = new int[referenceScore.length][];
        int totals[] = new int[referenceScore.length]; // total score for each team
        int teamRanks[] = new int[referenceScore.length];
        for (int row = 0; row < ranks.length; row++) {
            ranks[row] = new int[referenceScore[row].length];
            totals[row] = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < ranks[row].length; col++) {
                ranks[row][col] = getRank(referenceScore, row, col);
                totals[row] += referenceScore[row][col];
            }
        }
        for (int team = 0; team < teamRanks.length; team++) {
            teamRanks[team] = getTeamRank(totals, team);
        }
        System.out.println("          P1     P2     P3     P4     P5     P6   Total Rank");
        for (int row = 0; row < ranks.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("Team " + (row + 1) + " ");
            for (int col = 0; col < ranks[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d(%2d) ", referenceScore[row][col], ranks[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println(" " + totals[row] + "  " + teamRanks[row]);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output.

```
          P1     P2     P3     P4     P5     P6   Total Rank
Team 1 39(11) 40( 8) 17(17) 35(13) 42( 1)  6(18)   179   3
Team 2 40( 8) 41( 6) 27(15) 41( 6) 42( 1) 36(12)   227   1
Team 3 42( 1) 40( 8) 26(16) 42( 1) 42( 1) 35(13)   227   1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is way simpler than what I did :)